# Re-create template while switching routes

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

How can we re-create template while switching routes?

For example, i have **subscriber** template. It detects when user scrolls down to a display and subscribes to more data. It takes several parameters.

**Example:**
    **amazing_page.html**

```
{{#each}}
   {{amazing_topic}}
{{/each}}

{{>subscriber name='topics' count=5}}
```

**subscriber.js**

//rough sample code

```
Template.subscriber.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;
  var type = Template.currentData().name;
  var count = Template.currentData().count;
  var user = Template.currentData().user;
  var skipCount = 0;
    self.autorun(function(c){
    self.subscribe(type, skipCount, user);
    var block = true;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($(document).height()) && block) {
                block = false;
                skipCount = skipCount + count;
                console.log(type);
                console.log(skipCount);
                self.subscribe(type, skipCount, user, {
                    onReady: function() {
                        block = true;
                    },
                    onStop: function() {
                      console.log('stopped');
                    }
                });
        }
    });
  })
  });
```

I use this template with different parameters in different routes. 
The problem is if user switches some  routes, and scrolls down in one page, all subscribers he gets in another pages will actualy work in this page. More, they will store increased values for them variables, and will do all included logic.

I found a bad decision when we use  Route.getName (for example) comparing  and name parameter of subscriber. It is not a best option. Can someone help me to find a good practice for that?:)

**Simple Example:**

We have 3 different routes:

1)News
2)Videos
3)Topics

These routes templates have included special subscriber-templates. And subscribtion works fine on scroll.

Ok, now let's  visit all of them: News, Videos, Topics. 
Good, now scroll down and... I have three instance of subscriber template what will subscribe on them own publications, because they not destroyed when we switch routes.

And, as a result - when user scrolling Topics page, he will call subscribtion for News and Videos too, and he will take data from these collections too;) 
And - this is a problem:)

**UPD:** 
Looks like we find a decision. If i use Template.instance (autorun/subscribe)  it will start working expected, except some strange cases:)

First of all, when i go in another route in next iteration (scroll down) it returns me data from old, destroyed template + error. Next time (next iteration) it will start to subscribe to a correct data. Hmm...it looks like i have mistake in autorun section...or not?

**Attached print screen from console**
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Vrv.jpg)

Comment: It was hard to follow what the problem is, but it sounds to me like your subscriptions are not working.

Comment: Ok, again. 

For example we have 3 different routes: 

1)News
2)Videos
3)Topics

These routes have included special subscriber-templates. And subscribtion works fine on scroll

Ok, now let's  visit all of them: News, Videos, Topics. 
Good, now scroll down and... I have three instance of subscriber template what will subscribe on them own publications, because they not destroyed when we switch routes.

Comment: With code example: https://forums.meteor.com/t/re-create-template-while-switching-routes/28138

Comment: Are you using Blaze or something else (React, Angular, other, or mixture)?  If you are using Blaze, where are you subscribing to the publication?  There is a certain lifecycle for each of the above mentioned options, and you need to subscribe in the right place else you will get a persistent subscription instead of one that switches based on routing, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: I use Blaze+Flow-Router. I update the post with samples of code. Can you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have multiple subscriptions to the same collection and that therefore the list of documents shown in various contexts can change in unexpected ways. Meteor manages multiple subscriptions on the same collection by synchronizing the *union* of the selected documents.

The simplest way to manage each of your views is to make sure that the data context for a particular view uses a `.find()` with the query you need. This will typically be the same query that your publication is using.

A different but less efficient approach is to `.stop()` the subscription when you leave a view.

Comment: Hello, Michel! 
Thank you for reply!
No, actually i dont use multiple subscriptions. I have dynamical subscribtion, which  must change parameters, when i go in another route. Route have a master template, which have same subscriber-template, but with another parameters . And yes, you are absolutely right about .stop() in template.onDestroyed(). 

And yes, it work now for me. But, when i load another page i get this error in console: 

Uncaught Error: Can't call View#subscribe from inside the destroyed callback, try calling it inside created or rendered.

I will update question now.

Comment: You're doing `this.sub.stop()` but `this.sub` is the `autorun` function and not the subscription object itself!

Comment: Ehm...it was not updated code with part of experiments. In updated code i use Template.autorun and Template.subscribtion. Actually, it will stop tracking and subscribtions when template will destroyed.